# c++ pass constructor parameter from parent object to child object on creation

Tags: c++, class, struct, constructor

This question is so specific that I was having a lot of trouble finding an answer for it...

is there a way to pass a parent class' constructor parameter automatically to the constructor for a child class/struct within itself?

I want to read lines from a data file to populate my class and its children at creation, so I want to pass the data file into the child as well

my data structure is like this:

```
vector of class Par(ifstream parameter)
   membervar
   membervar
   vector of struct Chld(the same ifstream parameter)
       membervar
       vector membervar
```

and I'd like to be able to construct and fill all children and members by just calling the creation of the parent and giving it the datafile to read info from

```
vector<Par> parents(num, Par(datafile));
```

this would be my ideal creation line, quick and easy, and I can close the datafile right after because I have all of the info I need

is this even possible? wouldn't the default constructor just be called in the child? I was hoping not to have to go back in afterward to fill in the empty members of everything, but if I have to, I guess it can't be helped

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're doing, why not call all the constructors manually?

Comment: The phrases "parent class" and "child class" usually refer to inheritance. You appear to be using them in a non-standard sense which will mislead a lot of people.

Comment: hmm yeah you're probably right, I didn't know about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it?

```
class Par {
    std::vector<Chld> children;

public:
    Par(std::ifstream& file)
    { 
        children.push_back(Chld(file));  // pre-C++11
        children.emplace_back(file);     // post-C++11
    }
};
```

Comment: so I would have to use push_back? it won't just read the data as it creates the list like when initializing an array like {1, 2, 3, 4, etc}

Comment: @Kavukamari I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: is it impossible for the vector to be initial;ized all at once using data from the file like vector<double> vec(NUMBEROFITEMS, (some cin-like function that progresses the stream each time and grabs a double value))

Comment: @Kavukamari You could construct it with a pair of iterators: `vector<double> vec(std::istream_iterator<double>{input}, std::istream_iterator<double>{});`